# Given a field $K$ of characteristic $p>0$ and $f \in K[x]$ an irreducible polynomial, find the separable closure of $K$ in $L=K[x]/(f).$

Tags: field-theory, separable-extension

I have shown that we can find some irreducible, separable polynomial $g \in K[x]$ such that $f(x)=g(x^{p^n})$ for some $n \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}.$ What I have so far towards the problem in the title is the following:

Let $\alpha \in \overline{K}$ be a zero of $f \in K[x]$, so $L=K[x]/(f)=K(\alpha)$. By the first paragraph, $f(x)=g(x^{p^n})$ so $\alpha^{p^n}$ is a zero of the separable polynomial $g \in K[x]$. Therefore, $K(\alpha^{p^n})$ is a separable extension of $K,$ and $K(\alpha^{p^n}) \subset K(\alpha) = L$ so $K(\alpha^{p^n})$ is contained in $K_s,$ the separable closure of $K$ in $L$. I'm not sure what else I can say, or which directions to look in, so any hints would be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Working with what you have already shown, an important observation is the following: for any field, $K$, of characteristic $p>0$ and any element, $\newcommand{\al}{\alpha} \newcommand{\be}{\beta} \al$, that is algebraic over $K$, we have $(K(\al)/K)_s=(K(\al^p)/K)_s$ (here $(E/K)_s$ means the separable closure of $K$ in $E$, i.e. the set/ field of all elements of $E$ that are separable over $K$). You should try proving this on your own, but an explanation is given below if needed.

**Full explanation:**

> The reason the above statement works is due to a criterion for separability: that an element, $\al$, algebraic over some field, $K$ with characteristic $p>0$, is separable over $K$ iff $K(\al)=K(\al^p)$ (this even holds if $\al$ is not assumed to be algebraic over $K$). On the one hand it is obvious that $(K(\al)/K)_s\geq (K(\al^p)/K)_s$  (as $K(\al)\geq K(\al^p)$).
>  On the other hand, for any $\be\in K(\al)-K(\al^p)$, we have $\be^p\in K(\al^p)$ (you can see this by writing $\be=\sum_i k_i\al^i$ for some $k_i$s in $K$ and raising both sides to the $p$th power) and $\be\not\in K(\al^p)$, so $K(\be)\neq K(\be^p)$, i.e. $\be$ is inseparable over $K$. This means no element of $K(\al)-K(\al^p)$ is separable over $K$, so any element in $(K(\al)/K)_s$ must also lie in $(K(\al^p)/K)_s$, hence $(K(\al)/K)_s\leq (K(\al^p)/K)_s$. It follows that $(K(\al)/K)_s=(K(\al^p)/K)_s$.
>  It now follows pretty easily that the separable closure you are looking for is just $K(\al^{p^n})$, as $\al^{p^n}$ is separable over $K$, although in the same vein you could also say that the separable closure is $K(\al^{p^{n+1}})$ or $K(\al^{p^{n+2}})$, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the very helpful answer. Is it also true that the separable closure is equal to $K(\alpha)$? It seems to be, as repeated use of separability criterion you mention, gives $$K(\alpha)=K(\alpha^p)=\dots=K(\alpha^{p^n}).$$

Comment: @carraig Your observation is correct, but it only holds as long as $\alpha$ is separable over $K$, i.e. in the case where $f(x)$ itself is separable ($n=1$ basically). Otherwise one can only say that the separable closure equals $K(\alpha^{p^m})=K(\alpha^{p^{m+1}})=K(\alpha^{p^{m+2}})=\dots$ for all sufficiently large $m$, and not as much can be said about what happens with extensions $K(\alpha^{p^m})$ where $m$ is not big enough (aside from the fact that those extensions are distinct and as $m$ increases, they shrink).